# How to extract array from within json to a separate txt file

Tags: awk, grep, json

I have a .json file that I need to extract the SliceTiming field from into a separate txt file. I cannot use jq. If I could, my command would be

jq .SliceTiming[] *.json

Here is the .json file

```
{
"EchoTime": 0.033,
"RepetitionTime": 0.75,
"EffectiveEchoSpacing": 0.0005,
"SliceTiming": [
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145,
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145,
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145,
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145,
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145,
    0.51,
    0,
    0.365,
    0.0725,
    0.4375,
    0.2175,
    0.5825,
    0.2925,
    0.6575,
    0.145   ],
"PhaseEncodingDirection": "j-"}
```

Comment: If you can't use proper tools like `jq`, any guarantees how the json file is formatted wrt. white space, line endings etc.?

Comment: Are you allowed to use python?

Comment: python is allowed although I would prefer to use grep, sed, or awk if possible.

Comment: Why can't you use `jq`?

Comment: I am running on a server, which does not have jq installed and I can't install jq or anything else.

Comment: @Noah The server has an admin, right? The admin is there to make sure that the users can run their programs without issues. It's their job to make sure that you can run `jq`.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as python is allowed. This would be my preferred solution.

I don't feel comfortable dealing with sed, grep, awk as I do not know edge cases about the data.

#### Print array with , to stdout

```
cat data.json | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['SliceTiming']"
```

*Note:* This example uses python2.7, unlikely to work with python3.x

#### Just the values output. No `[]` no `,`:

Created `slice_out.py` as I couldn't find a nice way to do inline terminal

```
import sys, json
slice_data = json.load(sys.stdin)['SliceTiming']
for s in slice_data: print s
```

Ran with `cat data.json | python slice_out.py`

Comment: Great thank you! The output is another array in the format [ XX , XX , XX ,...,XX ]. I would like to get the output as each number on a separate line without commas. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've added another solution. Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl and the JSON module:

```
perl -MJSON -e 'print join("\n", @{decode_json(join("\n",<>))->{"SliceTiming"}})' <file.json
```

This outputs each number on a separate line without commas

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can't use this because i get an error.                                     
Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @Noah I guess you just have to install the JSON Perl module. It should be available as a package on your Unix (just like `jq`).